# js regexp - group priority

Tags: javascript, regex, grouping

Lets say, there are multiple regular expressions

1. `.+`
2. `(?:BBB )?CCC`

which are combined in single expression as groups - `/^(first) (second)$/`

Both groups should not "know" about each other (meaning - I can't change their expressions).

```
/^(.+) ((?:BBB )?CCC)$/.exec('AAA BBB CCC');
```

The current result:

```
 ["AAA BBB CCC", "AAA BBB", "CCC"]
```

The expected result:

```
 ["AAA BBB CCC", "AAA", "BBB CCC"]
```

How do I prioritize groups so that `BBB` ends up in the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the first `.+` (*which was inside the capturing group*) as [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) by adding the reluctant quantifier `?` next to  `+`

```
^(.+?) ((?:BBB )?CCC)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pY4yO5/1)

```
> /^(.+?) ((?:BBB )?CCC)$/.exec('AAA BBB CCC');
[ 'AAA BBB CCC',
  'AAA',
  'BBB CCC',
  index: 0,
  input: 'AAA BBB CCC' ]
```